# cakephp relation belongs To

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I'm using cakephp 2.1.3 and I have a table Ingredients and a table IngredientAliases
I want that in my page index in Ingredient when I select an IngredientAlias I want to see the IngredientAlias and some fileds of Ingredients
But I don't know if I have to make two query into my controller or only to set ingredients_id the id and cakephp in automatically retrieve me the data. Now I make two query in my controller but I don't know if it's the best way

```
$this->set('ingredient', $this->Ingredient->read());            $this->set('ingredient_alias',$this->Ingredient->IngredientAlias->read());
```

Here is my tables:

```
class Ingredient extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Ingredient';
    public $useTable = 'ingredients';
    public $belongsTo = 'User';

    public $hasMany = array (
        'IngredientAlias' => array (
            'className'     => 'IngredientAlias',
            'foreignKey'    => 'ingredient_id'
        )
    );
}

class IngredientAlias extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'IngredientAlias';
    public $useTable = 'ingredient_aliases';
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Ingredient' => array(
            'className'    => 'Ingredient',
            'foreignKey'   => 'ingredient_id'
        )
    );
}
```

And here is my IngredientsController (I have changed the routes to putt alias into my arguments and it's working)

```
public function edit ($alias) {
        $ing = $this->Ingredient->IngredientAlias->find('first', array(
                    'conditions' => array('IngredientAlias.alias' => $alias)));
        $this->Ingredient->IngredientAlias->id= $ing['IngredientAlias']['id'];
        $this->Ingredient->IngredientAlias->set('ingredient_id',$ing['IngredientAlias']['ingredient_id']);
        $this->Ingredient->id= $ing['IngredientAlias']['ingredient_id'];
        if (!$this->Ingredient->IngredientAlias->exists()) {
                throw new NotFoundException ('Nessuna corrispondenza trovata per questo ingrediente');
            }
            if (!$alias) {
                $this->set('flash_element','error');
                $this->Session->setFlash ('Ingrediente non valido');
            }
            $this->Ingredient->recursive = 2;
            $this->set('ingredient', $this->Ingredient->read());
            $this->set('ingredient_alias',$this->Ingredient->IngredientAlias->read());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the relations you described and if you have a `ingredient_id` key in your `ingredient_aliases` table if you call:

```
$this->Ingredient->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Ingredient.id' => $id)));
```

You would get the Ingredient record specified by $id with all it's associated IngredientAlias records in an array structure similar to the following:

```
Array =>
    [Ingredient] => Array
                        [id] => 3
                        [other_data_from_DB] =>
                        .....
    [IngredientAlias] => Array => 
                         [0] => Array =>
                                [id] => 1
                                [ingredient_id] => 3
                                [other_data_from_DB] =>
                                ....
                         [1] => Array =>
                                [id] => 2
                                [ingredient_id] => 3
                                [other_data_from_DB] =>
                                ....
                         [2] => Array =>
                                [id] => 3
                                [ingredient_id] => 3
                                [other_data_from_DB] =>
                                ....
```

The IngredientAlias array sub-structure is indexed because of the hasMany relation.
If you're not seeing the associated IngredientAlias records then check [your Model's recursive property](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive):

```
debug($this->Ingredient->recursive);
```

If it equals -1 then only the Ingredient Model data will be fetched. Check out what the other recursive values do in the link I provided.

If you want to go the other way around you should go through the IngredientAlias model:

```
$this->IngredientAlias->find('first', array(CONDITIONS));
```

will provide the specified in the CONDITIONS IngredientAlias record with it's connected Ingredient record. The Ingredient record will be only one because of the `IngredientAlias belongsTo Ingredient` relation.

Comment: But i want only the ingredientAlias with that alias, I think is a subquery because I have to search the id of the ingredient and the after the exact alias because I wanto only one IngredientAlias (the selected IngredientAlias)

Comment: Then just go the other way around - search for IngredientAlias and you will get the connected Ingredient record. ;)
So $this->IngredientAlias->find('first', array(CONDITIONS)); will provide what you need when you have both relations defined.

Comment: It is the same, but if you do everything according to the CakePHP conventions the framework will do it's magic for you and you wouldn't have to bother. 
Of course you can also do the so-called Ad-Hoc joins by specifying join conditions in the 'joins' key of a Model::find() call.
You can even write your custom SQL statement and call it with the Model::query() method, but again CakePHP will do it's magic for you, just as long as you follow the conventions.